# Switch beamer font families in general

Tags: beamer, fonts

A standard document (e.g. `scrreprt`) uses roman font family for text and Sansserif font family for titles etc. It is the other way round in `beamer`. How can I switch the two font families? Or why do `beamer` define the font families in this way?

For the background: I think this is my problem when using formulas, because they use the Sansserif font instead of the roman version. Formulas using the `euler` package look really poor.

P.S.: I compile with LuaLaTeX using TeXlive 2013.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The font families you use are usually set up by your beamer theme, the default being to use sans-serif everywhere. About the "why", it seems that sans-serif fonts prove easier to read on low-resolution projectors, but that's less of a problem nowadays, with more and more conference rooms equipped with modern hardware.

There are several ways you can change the fonts you use in a beamer presentation, only with latex. LuaLatex adds some features for loading TTF fonts and such, but that's probably more complicated than what you need here.

The easiest way is to use beamer font themes.

```
\usefonttheme[stillsansseriflarge]{serif}
```

You can also change the font family (and more) for every beamer template, with commands like (example taken in the manual):

```
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries} % Frame titles should be bold
```

You can refer to section 18 (Fonts) of the [beamer userguide](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) for more details and examples, and to section 5.6 (Choosing Appropriate Fonts and Font Attributes) for basic advice about fonts in presentations.