# ShareLatex font type in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

Is there an easy way to change the font type in ShareLatex? I've tried all of the instructions I could find on their website, but they do nothing.

Let's say, for example, that I wanted to use Windows font Arial in a beamer presentation. How would you do this?

Comment: I think it's more about the `beamer` document class rather than about ShareLatex. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125093/switch-beamer-font-families-in-general for changing font family. For Arial, this could help: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/arial