# Setting Font Family in Beamer Frame

Tags: beamer, fonts, pdftex

I must be drowning in a glass of water, but I am banging my head against the wall. I installed the emerald package to have new fonts I would like to use in my beamer presentation.

Please have a look at the code below, which compiles with pdflatex without any trouble. I can set the Augie font in the presentation slide with the institute name etc..., but I am not able to do the same inside e.g. a slide which begins with \begin{frame}.
I had a look at

[Define a separate font for slide titles in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130878/define-a-separate-font-for-slide-titles-in-beamer)

[Switch beamer font families in general](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125093/switch-beamer-font-families-in-general)

but I did not get very far. I am 99% sure the solution must be a one-liner, so any help is appreciated!

Cheers

####################################################################à

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usetheme{default}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseNone} % don't show bookmarks on initial view




% named colors
\definecolor{offwhite}{RGB}{249,242,215}
\definecolor{foreground}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{background}{RGB}{24,24,24}
\definecolor{title}{RGB}{107,174,214}
\definecolor{gray}{RGB}{155,155,155}
\definecolor{subtitle}{RGB}{102,255,204}
\definecolor{hilight}{RGB}{102,255,204}
\definecolor{vhilight}{RGB}{255,111,207}
\definecolor{lolight}{RGB}{155,155,155}
%\definecolor{green}{RGB}{125,250,125}

% use those colors
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=title}
\setbeamercolor{subtitle}{fg=subtitle}
\setbeamercolor{institute}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=foreground,bg=background}
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=foreground} % color of bullets
\setbeamercolor{subitem}{fg=gray}   
\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate subbody}{fg=gray}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{{\textendash}}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subitem}{size=\footnotesize}

% Now try to set te Augie font everywhere

\setbeamerfont{my frametitle}{series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{author}{series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{date}{series=\ECFAugie}





% page number
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\raisebox{5pt}{\makebox[\paperwidth]{\hfill\makebox[20pt]{\color{gray}
      \scriptsize\insertframenumber}}}\hspace*{5pt}}


% add a bit of space at the top of the notes page
\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}}


% a few macros
\newcommand{\bi}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\ei}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\ig}{\includegraphics}
\newcommand{\subt}[1]{{\footnotesize \color{subtitle} {#1}}}


  \title{Blockchain: Traceability, Provenance and Applications for My
    Unknown Institute}
 \framesubtitle{A researcher's perspective}
 \author{ {John Doe}}
 \institute{Unknown Institute} 
 \begin{document}

\frame{
\titlepage}


\begin{frame}  
\frametitle{What is a Blockchain}
% \framesubtitle{Test Frame}
%   \subt{An optional subtitle}
A distributed data structure which is
\begin{enumerate}
\item very difficult to tamper with
\item if tampered with, the tampering is easy to spot  
\end{enumerate}
And who invented it?
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\usetheme{default}` are superfluous
- with `\AtBeginDocument{\ECFAugie}` you can change the font of the normal text
- `\setbeamerfont{my frametitle}{series=\ECFAugie}` should be `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\ECFAugie}`
- `\framesubtitle{A researcher's perspective}` does not have any effect in the preamble, did you mean `\subtitle{A researcher's perspective}`?
- Things like

  ```
  \newcommand{\bi}{\begin{itemize}}
  \newcommand{\ei}{\end{itemize}}
  \newcommand{\ig}{\includegraphics}
  ```

  are not a good idea - they just obfuscater your code and makes it harder to read for anybody but you. You'll also loose functionality. If you want to save time, use an editor with auto complete and/or macros

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald}
%\usetheme{default}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{author}{series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{date}{series=\ECFAugie}

\AtBeginDocument{\ECFAugie}

\title{Blockchain: Traceability, Provenance and Applications for My  Unknown Institute}
\subtitle{A researcher's perspective}
\author{John Doe}
\institute{Unknown Institute} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}  
\frametitle{What is a Blockchain}
A distributed data structure which is
\begin{enumerate}
\item very difficult to tamper with
\item if tampered with, the tampering is easy to spot  
\end{enumerate}
And who invented it?
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

> Please consider carefully for which occasions you use such a font.