using emerald font in beamer slides as default
I am preparing some slides and I want to use the handwritten font emerald with beamer. I use pdflated. I have the following minimal example.
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald}

\author{The Author}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
\framesubtitle{Test subtitle}

\ECFAugie

test text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
\framesubtitle{Test subtitle}

test text
\end{frame}

\end{document}

The text in the second slide changes to emerald, but the third slide reverts back to the default. Is there some way to have the text continue to be in ECFAugie? Also how about the headings, tables, etc? Or mathematical notation/formulae/equations?

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{augie} ?

No, does not seem to have any effect for me.

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fau} ?

Yes, this works, but what does fau denote?

@user94293 Could you post this as an answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416857/setting-font-family-in-beamer-frame ? Then we could make this post a duplicate

@user3236841 "Or mathematical notation/formulae/equations" Augie has a very limited set of mathematical symbols. If you plan to use it in a math-heavy document you are bound to run into missing symbols. Reconsider your font choice if you need a lot of math, in particular as the fallback symbols will really stand out with such a font.

As an alternative to the solution mentioned in comments: if you have the augie font installed on your computer, you could use it with fontspec (requires compilation with lualatex or xelatex)
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{augie}

\author{The Author}
\title{Work Culture}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
\framesubtitle{Test subtitle}

test text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
\framesubtitle{Test subtitle}

test text

\[
a+b=c
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}



thanks! i have never used lualatex or xelatex in my 32 years of using latex. Btw, I think fontspec comes with other handwriting fonts. Thanks, though. Wonder if there is a good option with pdflatex.

@user3236841 fontspec does not come with any fonts. It uses the fonts installed on your computer, for example here an example with Darwin's handwriting: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165087/36296. Didn't you already get a good option for pdflatex in comments?

Thank you fro the additional information. This is useful for newbies like me to know.
